# Store ASCII text in a memory area in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

STRING2 is defined like `STRING2 SPACE  0xFF` in ARM7 assembly program. 
A register r6 = 0x00000074
with ASCII values at that address memory location = `123 the...`
How to store this `123 the..` text in STRING2

Comment: Load the address of `STRING2` into a register and use a loop to copy the characters one by one.

Comment: I think loading can be done like ADR r2, STRING2 so after this r2 points to STRING2. So what i understand from you is. Now copy the value in r6 memory location to r2's memory location?  Does STRING2 when defined like above does it have any particular address or it gets assigned a random address. And when you do ADR r2, STRING2 then you can check the address of STRING2 which will get stored in r2. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: I am somewhat confused how does things like - `STRING1 DCB  "the the the 123 the" ` and `STRING2 SPACE  0xFF` get handled by assembler. whats the difference between the two

Comment: `SPACE 0xFF` means put 255 (0xFF) zero bytes. It's a shorthand for `DCB 0,0,0...,0` with 255 zeroes. The address for `STRING2` is "random", it gets assigned by the linker.

Comment: if you are running big endian as stated in a prior question (first off why would you ever run an arm big endian, even an xscale) then that string might end up byteswapped when you read it back so how you copy it matters and how you read it back after being copied matters.

Comment: combination of assembler and linker assign the address for the label STRING2 as with any other label.

Comment: did you manage to make two users with the same name?